# How to check if a directory is empty or not in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

In Java we use below code to check if directory is empty or not. Can someone kindly help me to do this in Gradle

```
private static boolean isDirEmpty(final Path directory) throws IOException {
    try(DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory)) {
        return !dirStream.iterator().hasNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in gradle you can simply do `file(projectDir).list().size() == 0`

Comment: enough to say `!file(projectDir).list()` to check if empty